# Why does NULL Pointer check not work while iterating through singly-linked list in C?

Tags: c, loops, pointers, null, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to print from heap. If I come across a NULL pointer I should print NULL; otherwise, print it's value.

Sample output:

```
1   [2]
2   null
3   null
4   [7, 3]
5   null
6   [7]
```

But my code keeps crashing for dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Here is the code that I wrote to test:

```
void printResult(IntList* intL, int nNode, int nEdge)
{
    int i;
    for (i; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if (intRest((intL))
        {
            printf("%d", intFirst((intL)[i]));
            intRest((intL)[i]);
        }
        else
            printf(" NULL ");
    }
}

//Here is the definition of functions:
//First
int intFirst(IntList oldL)
{
    return oldL->element;
}

/** rest
 */
IntList intRest(IntList oldL)
{
    return oldL->next;
}
//=================
struct IntListNode
{
    int element;
    IntList next;
};

//===================
typedef struct IntListNode * IntList;
```

Comment: Side note: `typedef struct IntListNode * IntList;` wasn't good idea. It's rather confusing.

Comment: `for (i; i <= 10; i++)` what is this? 2) `if (intRest((intL))` what is `intRest()` and why do you need double parentheses?

Comment: The code compiles, but it crashes as soon as it reaches a NULL.

Comment: I would doubt that it compiles.

Answer (score 8):

You have singly linked list consisting of nodes that are not stored in a continuous block of memory (they are rather scattered), thus trying to iterate through its elements this way:

```
for (i; i <= 10; i++)
    printf("%d", intFirst((intL)[i]));
```

results in *undefined behavior* since you are accessing the wrong memory. You should do something like:

```
struct IntListNode * ptr = *intL;
while (ptr) {
    printf("%d", ptr->element);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

Comment: When I'm trying to compile ptr = ptr->next; it gives me this error msg: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2888425: Probably because you passed an argument of type `IntList* intL` which is due to your confusing typedef actually `struct IntListNode **`. Try to avoid creating aliases that hide information that it is actually a pointer.

Comment: @user2888425: Also note that while defining `next` within your structure, it seems to be more appropriate to define its type as `struct IntListNode*` explicitly.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. I tried different variation of IntList and IntListNode, but couldn't make it work. I think the issue is that I cannot traverse the list. Is there way that I can walk the list by initializing a higher level pointer or something similar to that?

Comment: @user2888425: The traversing through nodes should look the way I wrote in my answer. Check this tutorial, maybe it will make things more clear for you: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html

Answer (score 4):

If

```
IntList intRest(IntList oldL)
{
    return oldL->next;
}
```

is your test for NULL in `if (intRest((intL))`,

then your code will crash if intL == NULL.

Comment: @LihO It's one of the problems. The problem you highlight is important, too. But both will need to be fixed.